ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED After deploying Angular app to Render.com
My deployed render app is not able to get the backend data. I also cannot try to login or register.
Opening the app in firefox rather than chrome shows another error: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/api/foods. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)."
Link to app: https://food-store-angular.onrender.com/
Github link: https://github.com/dannyj172/Food-Store-Angular/
Image of console errors

if it's hitting localhost, the deployed version thinks it's not production.

Thank you! I needed to import the environment.prod.ts instead of environment.ts in my url.ts file!

you won't need to do that... just be sure you have: "fileReplacements": [
{
"replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
"with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
] In your angular.json file... in build>configurations... ng build should replace the file for you.  I see that's missing in your github's angular.json file.

ng serve section won't need that.  The idea is that when ng build is run, it replaces the file.... ng serve just uses environment.ts.
